# Webhook messenger FB API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to activate the receipt of facebook messages on my webhook, but according to the facebook documentation there is no longer an option .. for example, in the print below I am looking for the "messages" permission but it does not exist anymore ...

[image]

Currently I installed the messenger component in my application, however I realized that if I go manually and activate the receipt of the pages it works, however as I said "manual", I would like to automate this via the option of "subscriptions".
[image]

I added in my code the sending of the "messages" field, however it also has no effect ...

```
 $facebook = new Facebook();
            $facebook->setDefaultAccessToken($page['access_token']);
            //?subscribed_fields=leadgen
            $response = $facebook->post(
                '/' . $page['id'] . '/subscribed_apps',
                [
                    'subscribed_fields' => [
                        'leadgen',
                        'feed',
                        'messages',
                    ],
                ],
                $page['access_token']
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in the UI you have to do it in the Messenger products settings, not Webhook settings(your first screenshot).

This guide explains how to do it:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/getting-started/app-setup#setting-up-your-facebook-app

https://developers.facebook.com/apps/<app_id>/messenger/settings